Interaction with a contract in Frontend
I am making this error
ethers.js?v=3fc7d2ac:325 Uncaught (in promise) Error: contract runner does not support calling (operation="call", code=UNSUPPORTED_OPERATION, version=6.13.3)

I am attempting to interact with my getProle functon in my frontend.
Here is my code:
export const getProfile = async (signer) => {
    const contract = new ethers.Contract(contractAddress, abi, signer);
    console.log('signer',signer)
    const userAddress = await signer; // Get the user's wallet address 
    const profile = await contract.methods.getProfile(userAddress).call;
    console.log('profile',profile)
    return profile;
};
const connect = async()=>{
    console.log('d',walletAddress.value)
     
      const signer = await connectWallet();
      console.log('sssigner',signer)
      walletAddress.value = await signer.getAddress();
      const profile = await getProfile(walletAddress.value)
      console.log('dd',walletAddress.value)
      onsole.log('ddp',profile)
    //   const profile = await getProfile(walletAddress.value)
     
       formattedAddress.value = `${walletAddress.value.substring(0, 6)}...${walletAddress.value.substring(walletAddress.value.length - 4)}`;
      console.log('ss',formattedAddress.value)
}

